# Unable to edit Tomcat Java options in XAMPP

Tags: java, tomcat, solr, xampp, tomcat7

I'm looking to get an instance of Solr search running on my localhost. The [directions](http://www.icuriousmedia.com/blog/how-to-install-apache-solr-on-windows-xp-1439.php) call for pointing Tomcat to the Solr home directory by editing

> C://Xampp/tomcat/bin/tomcat7w.exe

and modifying the Java options tab.

When I try to open the file I get this error:

> "The specified service does not exist as an installed service. Unable to open the service 'tomcat7'"

When I initiate Tomcat on XAMPP and navigate to localhost:8080, it seems all is well.

Comment: did you install tomcat as a windows service?

Comment: tomcat7 is included with XAMPP. Plus it's obviously installed since the localhost:8080 points me to the Tomcat menu

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is installed, but is it installed *as a Windows service*? Check in Control Panel/Administrative/Services. If it is, open its properties and note the short name. Then rename Tomcat7w.exe to XXXXXw.exe where XXXXX is the short name. If it isn't installed as a service, go to the Tomcat bin directory and type `service install Tomcat7`.

Comment: If its listed as 'Tomcatx' in services, then no I don't have it as a Windows service. There is no 'service install Tomcat7', there is a service.bat but that doesn't do anything. The Tomcat7.exe only opens a command window for a half second and then nothing happens

Comment: Ah, it wasn't in the bin directory. If I go to the Tomcat root folder, there is a tomcat_service_install.bat. Now it works. Thanks!

Comment: 'service install Tomcat7' does that. I didn't say there was a command file by that name, that is what to type, that's why the quotes.

Comment: Um, ok. If you're in Windows, you don't need to type anything.

Comment: @AlxVallejo If you're in Windows *and it is already installed as a service* you dont need to type anything. The error message you got indicates that there was something wrong with the service installation. This answer is about how to fix that.

Comment: Thanks @EJP. You saved the day :)